# Using service to communicate between nodes in different package

Tags: ros, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
The tutorial gives an example of communication between nodes in the same package. Is it possible to use service to communicate between nodes in different package? Does that mean I should load two manifests?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10512/using-service-to-communicate-between-nodes-in-different-package/) by [roboren](https://answers.ros.org/users/609/roboren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2011-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it is definitely possible.

You just define the service in any package (e.g. package A) and make package A a dependency for the packages using the service.
Of course, a package can use its own service, too.

[This question](http://answers.ros.org/question/1467/custom-msg-for-diference-package) is the same in principle (just for messages):

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3